# vuejs + d3: select returns element, but attr() returns null

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vuejs2, getattribute

I'm confused a bit, please help me to figure out a problem.

I am using VueJS + d3.js.

I have a code that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class='chart-frame-chart-comp border-black-1 border-radius-1'>
    <div class='plot'>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as d3 from 'd3'

export default {
  name: 'chart-frame-chart-comp',

  mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(this.plot)
  },

  methods: {
    plot () {
      console.log(this.getPlotSize())
    },

    getPlotSize () {
      let a = d3.select('.chart-frame-chart-comp .plot')
      console.log('a', a)
      let b = a.attr('tagName')
      console.log('b', b)
      return b
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In `getPlotSize` I am trying to return an attribute of a selected element (the one with `.plot` class)

So in debugger, I see output:

[image]

Obviously, d3 managed to obtain a `node` (since it is the actual element, I was looking for plus selection return only one element that, again, I was looking for). But when d3 tries to return value of `getAttribute`, former returns null and `hasAttribute` returns `false`. But Chrome debugger sees that element has those attributes:

[image]

Obviously I'm missing something! So my question is: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of posting images post your code!

Comment: @UllasHunka updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misconception as there is no attribute `tagName` on your node. What you see in your console is the [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) property of the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) you selected. At the time you are selecting the element—as shown in your second screenshot— there are two attributes, namely `class` and `data-v-391ae376`. Hence, neither `.getAttribute("tagName")` nor D3's `.attr("tagName")` will return any value.

If you are interested in the element's `tagName` you can simply call [`selection.node()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_node) to get the first element in the selection and access its `tagName` property afterwards. In your example this will print `"div"`.

```
getPlotSize () {
  let a = d3.select('.chart-frame-chart-comp .plot');
  console.log('a', a);
  let b = a.node().tagName;   // Get the DOM node and read its tagName property
  console.log('b', b);
  return b;
}
```

Comment: thank you for response! You are right, returning `node()` resolved my problem :)